# Some techniques to replace infinitives?

Tags: infinitives

My English teacher doesn't like infinitives and she wants me to replace most if not all of them in my essays. Writing them is habitual for me and I always catch myself writing them but I'm always unsure of how to revise it without sounding awkward.

What are some ways I can replace infinitives in my sentences?

Comment: Could you provide an example or five? (Preferably not just of any sentences with infinitives you'd normally write, but of those your teacher has expressly criticized.) Thanks!

Comment: Yes, examples please. I don't think your teacher can 'not like infinitives' - rather that there are some particular constructions that she wants you to avoid them in. So to take I.J.Kennedy's example, 'He liked' takes a verbal noun rather than an infinitive, but 'He wanted' must take an infinitive.

Comment: They are a perfectly valid and important part of the English language. An infinitive or gerund is often interchangeable, though in some cases not.

Comment: You must be using infinitives in places where they aren't supposed to be used.  No grammarian (that I have heard of) thinks that infinitives should be avoided as much as possible.  Examples are definitely needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He liked to eat bananas → He liked eating bananas.

Answer (score 1):

You might like [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/384/how-does-one-know-when-to-use-a-gerund-or-a-infinitive/388#388) to a question on infinitives vs. gerunds.