# How to use "to + V-ing"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, infinitives, gerunds

I saw some scenarios that used the structure "to + V-ing", such as the following:

- *Looking forward to hearing*.
- *Disposed to using* few words.
- I would like to *apply* what I learned in school *to helping* make more money.
- This is the closest we *have come to winning* the league.

When can I use this structure? I'm confused about that.

Comment: Related: [When should a verb be followed by a gerund instead of an infinitive](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/when-should-a-verb-be-followed-by-a-gerund-instead-of-an-infinitive) and [How does one know when to use a gerund or an infinitive](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/384/how-does-one-know-when-to-use-a-gerund-or-a-infinitive)

Comment: @Thuan: What you  call "the structure to + v-ing" is not a structure. _To_ is a preposition, and like all prepositions it can take a gerund object. _Disposed **to using**, exhausted **from using**, guilty **of using**, interested **in using**, talking **about using**,_ etc. They're just prepositional phrases. Why use _to_? Because the predicates _look forward, disposed, apply,_ and _come_ -- in these senses -- require the preposition _to_, that's why. Nothing special here, really.

Answer (score 29):

In English, the form V + -ing is called a *gerund* if it serves as a noun. For example, the gerund form of "run" is "running". (I like cats, I like dogs, I like running). However, not all V + ing forms are gerunds--in "I am running", "running" is another verb.

This [blog post](http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/2010/03/gerunds-and-infinitives-to-gerund.html) explains that there are a few cases where you use *to + V + -ing*:

> 1) If the *to* is part of a phrasal verb or verb + preposition combination:

A *phrasal verb* is something like "look forward to", "confess to", etc. In this case, the "to" is part of the verb itself. Some examples are:

- I am looking forward to attending the party
- I am committed to supporting the Linguistics proposal on Area51

> 2) If the *to* is part of an adjective + preposition combination:

For example:

- A lot of women aren’t accustomed to being treated so well!
- I am opposed to increasing taxes.

These look similar to the examples above, but you can tell that a word like *accustomed* is an adjective in this case because there is a form of the verb *to be*. That is, you *are* an adjective.

> 3) If the *to* is part of a noun + preposition combination:

For example:

- His addiction to gambling has caused a lot of stress for his family.
- Her great dedication to teaching inspires her students.

---

Going through your examples, "I would like to apply what I learned in school to helping make more money" is incorrect, and doesn't fit into any of these categories (hat tip: Karl Knechtel).

Comment: "I would like to apply what I learned in school to helping make more money" sounds wrong to me, and as far as I can tell it doesn't fit in any of those listed categories, either.

Comment: @Karl: very true. Added a bit to my answer, with credit to you

Comment: I think this is a bit too complicated as it says the same thing three times over. In short: the gerund is used because *to* is a preposition in these cases (i.e. you need a noun after it, and out of all verb forms only the gerund can function as a noun).

Comment: Oh, and the third example fits just fine into the first category. (It's the "helping make more money" part that is strange, but the "apply X to <gerund>" part is perfectly grammatical.)

Comment: @RegDwight: Exactly. There's nothing wrong with the OP's example except for a stylistic flabbiness.

Comment: Is the sentence "I would like to apply what I learned in school to helping make more money" incorrect?

Comment: Your examples in 1) don't have the gerunds. Also, what do you mean by "That is, you are an adjective"?

Comment: @bog: because in 1 they aren't gerunds, just the verb with ing. And I meant you are an adj in the sense that you need a verb of being. Ex I am short

Comment: @simchona there should be a name for "verb+ing" (I will search tomorrow if I don't forget) , and also there is no such thing after "to" in the examples in 1).Please read your examples and compare with the original blog.

Comment: "Understanding the modular approach to installing IIS", is a title of a book section I'm reading and as far a I understand is in case 3 (noun + preposition combination)

Answer (score 7):

It's a bit tricky but you have to learn to tell whether the "To" is being used as (A.) part of an Infinitive or (B.) a Preposition.

Once you develop this skill, you can follow this:

Infinitive "To" = to + base verb

Preposition "To" = to + Noun, Pronoun, V+ing

Examples of Infinitive "To" are:

would like to + base verb

plan to + base verb

decide to + base verb

etc.

Examples of Preposition "To" are:

go to + Noun

look forward to + Noun/ V+ing

be used to + Noun/ V+ing

allergic to + Noun

etc.

Hope this helped!

;-)