# Should I use the phrase: "to + verb-ing" or just "to + verb"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use to + V-ing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38964/how-to-use-to-v-ing)

I don't know what is correct in the two sentences below:

> - I work everyday to learning new technologies.
> - I work everyday to learn new technologies.

If you can tell me what is correct, please explain to me why.

Comment: I know second one is the correct one.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38964/how-to-use-to-v-ing

Comment: @Bogdan Lătăianu: Thanks, it's exactly what I need to learn.

Comment: I know this question is closed, but a specific point *not* covered by the linked topic is that in OP's example here, the more common form would be *I work everyday* **at** *learning new technologies.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*To learn* is the only correct choice; the phrase acts as a single unit called an "infinitive".  *To learning* is just not the way English does infinitives.

Comment: What about `I am looking forward to hearing from you`. Thanks

Comment: Could you please give me an example about use "to + verb-ing"?

Comment: @Braveyard: In that case, there is no infinitive.  *Looking forward to* is a separate unit from *hearing*, which is a gerund.

Comment: @viet: I don't understand.

Comment: @drɱ65 δ: Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: @Daniel: Perhaps a nice example wold be to compare "I look forward to see you (because you're standing in front of me)" versus "I look forward to seeing you".  The former uses "looK" and "forward" as a literal verb and adverb, along with an infinitive "to see".  The latter uses "look forward to" as an idiomatic verb phrase with an integrated preposition.  Another usage would be "I look forward to the right of the next buoy", which would combine a literal verb and adverb with a literal preposition.