# "Imperative to" + "-ing" suffix

Tags: imperatives

Is it correct to write: "An agreement is imperative to tackling the problem"?

Or should it be: "An agreement is imperative to tackle the problem"?

Thanks

Comment: [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38964/how-to-use-to-v-ing) may help

Comment: Different adjectives *(imperative, vital, necessary, central, fundamental)* allow different constructions. Personally I'd associate *imperative* with the earlier ones in that list, and stick with the infinitive (OP's second option).

Comment: In this case "to" is not a preposition but means "in order to" which requires the infinitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are my recommendations:

"An agreement is imperative for tackling the problem"

"An agreement is imperative (in order) to tackle the problem"

Answer (score 0):

here "to" is not a part of the adjective "imperative". so that here "to" will take verb form of "tackle".   so "An agreement is imperative to tackle the problem"? is right.