# imperative to -ing

Tags: grammaticality, gerund-vs-infinitive, predicate-frames

Which one is right?

1. the degree is imperative to consolidating my grasp on concepts and keeping me abreast of upcoming upgrades
2. the degree is imperative to consolidate my grasp on concepts and keep me abreast of upcoming upgrades.

Comment: Compare: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/247054/imperative-to-ing-suffix

Comment: I realize that it's a similar question. The reason I posted it nevertheless is that I couldn't reach a conclusion. No reason to downvote, I suppose. @TaliesinMerlin

Comment: I didn't downvote your question.

Answer (score 0):

According to Reverso.context.net there are only examples of "imperative to Infinitive" like:

The full access to the Internet and the Internet-based enterprise development became ***imperative to consolidate*** the ongoing transition process.

Compare (also from Reverso.context.net):

Most importantly, we are not oblivious to the ***imperative of consolidating*** peace through enhanced political dialogue, tolerance and ensuring a free and fair electoral process.