# Difference between a gerund acting as subject and an infinitive acting as a subject?

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive

I am wondering whether there is any difference between a gerund acting as subject and an infinitive acting as a subject.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. Please could you show me an example of an infinitive acting as a subject?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/384/how-does-one-know-when-to-use-a-gerund-or-an-infinitive but this question isn't clear enough to me to feel sure.

Comment: I am not sure what kind of a difference you mean -- difference in structure, meaning or usage.

Comment: If you have great interest in the idea, try this, may be there's some useful info in there: paginaspersonales.deusto.es/urbina/Inglés/to-ing%20subjects.pdf

Comment: [I've answered this question several times](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+mccawley+infinitive+gerund). Take your pick.

Comment: I'm sure there's a similar question about something like "to go to the beach" vs "going to the beach", where the latter is more focused on the process of traveling, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 6):

*The Grammaring Guide to English Grammar* has this to say.
[Gerund as Subject](http://www.grammaring.com/the-gerund-as-subject)

> A gerund clause can be the subject of a sentence:
>    - **Hiking** can be a relaxing and rewarding activity.
>    - **Swimming in the winter** can boost your immune system.
>    - **Learning a foreign language** is easier at a young age.
>   The use of the gerund as subject is more common than that of the *to*-infinitive.

[Infinitive as Subject](http://www.grammaring.com/the-to-infinitive-as-subject)

> A *to*-infinitive clause can be the subject of a sentence:
>    - **To tell the truth** is always right.
>    - **To complain** would seem ungrateful.
>   But it is more common to start with the introductory it and place the *to*-infinitive clause at the end of the sentence:
>    - **It is** always right **to tell the truth**.
>    - **It would seem** ungrateful **to complain**.

If you have great interest in the idea, try [this](http://paginaspersonales.deusto.es/urbina/Ingl%C3%A9s/to-ing%20subjects.pdf), may be there's some useful info in there.

Comment: Nice piece, that final link; but I stumbled somewhat over Duffley's first example: "To have the Greek paper is not the great help that at first flush it seemed" vs. "Having the Greek paper is not the great help that at first flush it seemed." For WCs in Greece generally have signs saying *not* to flush the paper but to put it in a bin! ;-)

Comment: @BrianDonovan Either way, can't say it doesn't wash.

Answer (score 2):

Erring is human; forgiving is divine. I have here ruined the meter of [Pope’s line](http://poetry.eserver.org/essay-on-criticism.html) (“To err is human; to forgive, divine”), but I for one cannot detect a jot of difference in meaning. So my admittedly “[opinion-based](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4784/what-is-wrong-with-opinion-based)” answer is, “nothing but rhythm.”