# Can an infinitive noun phrase be used as the subject of a question?

Tags: questions, infinitives, noun-phrases

It is fine to say:

> To get the details is very important

But is it OK to say:

> Is to get the details very important?

Comment: I'd put it as marginally acceptable. Extraposition would be the more common option in both examples, but in the question form it comes very close to being _required_.

Comment: [Difference between a gerund acting as subject and an infinitive acting as a subject?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177437/difference-between-a-gerund-acting-as-subject-and-an-infinitive-acting-as-a-subj). As advised above, "It is very important to get the details. / Is it very important to get the details?" are more idiomatic.

Comment: *Is to err human? Is to forgive divine?*

Comment: It sounds awkward to me. I'd say *Is getting the details very important?*

Comment: Thanks for that major clue, deadrat. To err and to get are human and to forgive, divine.

However, give *err* any detail and it needs a preposition… or does *to err detail/a detail/the detail* work?

Aren’t *to err on detail/about a detail/over the detail* needed?

Is that an extension of user140086’s gerund/infinitive suggestion? I get confused by such…