# To smoke vs Smoking at the beginning of the sentence

Tags: differences, gerunds, gerund-vs-infinitive, sentence-starts

I have been taught that we can use either of "**to INF**" or "**Verb-ing**" at the beginning of the sentence as a subject, which leads me to a point of confusion.

Here is my confusion:

> A: To smoke is not good for all.
>   B: Smoking is not good for all.

These two sentences both mean the same thing to me.

Could you guys explain the difference and then can we use that explanation to demonstrate  other such sentences with?

Comment: They do have the same meaning - who has told you otherwise?

Comment: @KateBunting some books I use smoking but they have an answer is to smoke. I really don't know why.

Comment: The habit of smoking tobacco is usually referred to as _smoking_, so B is the more natural sentence. However, it is possible to use an infinitive as the subject of a sentence, so A is grammatical and has the same meaning.

Comment: @KateBunting so I guess A seems like a warning and B seems like useful for the context of teaching about smoking, is that right?

Comment: "Smoking is bad for you" is a health warning. A native speaker would be unlikely to say "To smoke is not good for you", but they might say "To smoke now would be bad manners" referring to a particular instance rather than the habit in general.

Comment: @KateBunting thank you so much. I got it clearly now.

Comment: @KateBunting It's not good for you to smoke, you know. Neither are fish. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one know when to use a gerund or an infinitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/384/how-does-one-know-when-to-use-a-gerund-or-an-infinitive) The general answer for subjects (and other usages, though cases where there are different meanings, as in _He stopped to smoke / He stopped smoking_, are not covered) is given in the accepted answer.