# "to think about" in the beginning of a sentence

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

Can someone explain to me what this sentence means?
I got confused about why it had "to think about" at the beginning of a sentence.
"To think about income elasticity analogous to a price
elasticity of demand."

Comment: Please complete the sentence and explain the problem.

Comment: That's not a sentence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one know when to use a gerund or an infinitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/384/how-does-one-know-when-to-use-a-gerund-or-an-infinitive) An answer addresses to-infinitives as subjects and as complements. _To know her is to love her._