# Problem with gerund and infinitive

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

I'm confusing with use of gerund or infinitive, I don't know which one of them I should use, for example ;

*I'm looking for a function to reverse a string

I'm looking for a function for reversing a string*

can someone tell me which one is correct and why ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you assume only one can be correct? That's usually the wrong way to bet, unless there's an ESL textbook in the woodpile. Both are in fact grammatical and colloquial, and both mean the same thing. The infinitive _to reverse a string_ will be interpreted as a purpose infinitive, and the _for_ with the gerund is the normal purpose marker. As usual, there is a choice, and people will vary, often from minute to minute, in which one they use in which context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one know when to use a gerund or an infinitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/384/how-does-one-know-when-to-use-a-gerund-or-an-infinitive)

Comment: *I'm looking for a function **that reverses** a string*. They're all fine. And that's not to mention *I'm looking for a **string-reversing** function*.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment John Lawler wrote:

> Why do you assume only one can be correct? That's usually the wrong way to bet, unless there's an ESL textbook in the woodpile. Both are in fact grammatical and colloquial, and both mean the same thing. The infinitive *to reverse a string* will be interpreted as a purpose infinitive, and the *for* with the gerund is the normal purpose marker. As usual, there is a choice, and people will vary, often from minute to minute, in which one they use in which context.